# Error when doing delete and commit with sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I get an error I don't understand when I do session commit after a deletion like this: (in a shell with flask app context or anywhere while running the app)

```
>>> from app.extensions import db
>>> from app.models.user import User
>>> user = User.query.all()[0]
>>> db.session.delete(user)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

> File
>   "/Users/hugo/Dropbox/lahey/api/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
>   line 962, in module
>       % (self._il_path, self._il_addtl)) ImportError: importlater.resolve_all() hasn't been called (this is sqlalchemy.orm
>   strategy_options)

My model for the object I try to delete looks like this:

```
import datetime
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.password import PasswordType
from sqlalchemy_utils import force_auto_coercion

from app.extensions import db

# Setup coercion of passwords
force_auto_coercion()


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(PasswordType(schemes=['pbkdf2_sha512']), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(256))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Deleting objects of other models works fine. Could this somehow be because I'm using the PasswordType column from sqlalchemy_utils?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out what caused this. I've been using package [sqlalchemy_bulk_lazy_loader](https://github.com/operator/sqlalchemy_bulk_lazy_loader)
which had a bug (strategy_options was not imported in a correct way). The issue is now [fixed in the package](https://github.com/operator/sqlalchemy_bulk_lazy_loader/issues/2)

See full [sqlalchemy mail list thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlalchemy/kz47tCpbf-A/oIju9hs9AQAJ) for full details

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Flask`, the docsting says you are wrong configuring the `Column`:

> ```
> Lazy configuration of the type with Flask config:
>
>         import flask
>         from sqlalchemy_utils import PasswordType, force_auto_coercion
>
>         force_auto_coercion()
>
>         class User(db.Model):
>
>             __tablename__ = 'user'
>
>             password = db.Column(
>                 PasswordType(
>                     # The returned dictionary is forwarded to the CryptContext
>                     onload=lambda **kwargs: dict(
>                         schemes=flask.current_app.config['PASSWORD_SCHEMES'],
>                         **kwargs
>                     ),
>                 ),
>                 unique=False,
>                 nullable=False,
>             )
> ```